# why does my website stops loading on aws ec2 instance randomly once in a while?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a t2.micro ec2 instance on us-west-2a and instance's state is all green.

When I access my website it stops loading once in a while. Even if I reboot it, the website still doesn't load. When I stop an instance and then relaunch it, it shows 1/2 status checks failed.

ALARM TYPE: awsec2-i-20aaa52c-High-Network-Out

Comment: the alarm says "high network out". Do you have a large amount of outbound traffic? Can you connect to the instance via ssh to look at the logs?

Comment: @tedder42 I notice bunch of weird curl/wget/ calls to luxsocks.ru and http://174.122.42.230/luxx in var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: those are attempts to exploit your server.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same type of issue.

EC2 instances were failing Instance Status Checks after a stop/start. I was able to take a look on my side at the System logs available to support and I could confirm that the system was having a kernel panic and was unable to boot from the root volume.

So I launched new EC2 temporary instance so we can attach the EBS root volumes of each EC2 instance . Here we modified the grub configuration file so it can load from a previous kernel.

The following commands:
1. Mount the EBS volume as a secondary volume into mnt folder: $ sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt 
2. Backup the grub.cfg file: sudo cp /mnt/boot/grub2/grub.cfg grub.cfg_backup 
3. Edit the grub.cfg file: sudo vim /mnt/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
4. Here we commented # all the lines for the first entry loading the new kernel. 
Then you attached the original EBS volumes back to the original EC2 instances and these EC2 instances were able to successfully boot.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html#FilesystemKernel